# How to get nested data from gson?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson, resttemplate

I did a get request to a external RESTful api and receive as response a json object with this structure:

```
{
    "data": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "John Doe",
       "email": "doe@john.com",
       "urlPicture": "urlPicture.com/82819",
       "address": {
          "street": "My street",
          "number": "29",
          "city": "Nurnberg",
          "country": "Germany"
       }
    }
}
```

I don't need all stuff of this response, I want only some fields to save in a database.

My POJO classes are similar to this pseudocode:

```java
    public class Data{
        private User user;

        // getters and setters
    }

    public class User{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String urlPicture;
        private String country;

        // getters and setters
    }
```

But, when I try to extract fields that I want, I receive null in this fields

````java
    public void testResponse(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Data data = new Data();
        User user = new User();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://apifrommyrequest.com/user/{id}",
                    String.class,
                    73442);
        user = gson.fromJson(response, User.class);
        System.out.println(user);
    }
    ```

My output:
22:20:57.641 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP GET https://apifrommyrequest.com/user/73442
22:20:57.672 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
22:20:58.243 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 200 OK
22:20:58.247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
Data(id=0, name=null, urlPicture=null, country=null)

I really don't know how to do anymore.
````

Comment: That's not valid JSON. `country` in User won't work, since it is part of a sub-object.

Comment: So, I need to construct an inner class for a nested object, right?

So, why other data doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know how the response really looks like, so I can't tell. Please fix the JSON in your example.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to fix it, if continue to give an error, I'll edit the question. Thank you

Comment: To start, print your `response`. And `RestTemplate` is capable of doing the deserialization for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the below code. You can't directly access the country, it is a value placed in a nested object. And also since response body returns as data you can't convert it to a User object. first, you need to convert it to a Data object.

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String urlPicture;
    private Address address;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Address {
    private String country;

    // getters and setters
}

public void testResponse(){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Data data = new Data();
    User user = new User();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String response = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "https://apifrommyrequest.com/user/{id}",
                String.class,
                73442);
    data = gson.fromJson(response, Data.class);

    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can design your POJO like this too(to reduce nested POJOs):

```
public class Data {
    private User data;

   //getters and setters
}

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String urlPicture;
    private String country;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    private void unpackNested(Map<String,String> elements)
    {
        this.country = elements.get("country");

    }
   //getters and setters
}
```

Then finally deserialize on Data class

Answer (score 0):

you dont really need to do the conversion from string to object, resttemplate already use jackson that do it for u , just have to

```
YourObject response = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://apifrommyrequest.com/user/{id}",
                    YourObject.class,
                    73442);
```

then it is going to do the mapping to your pojo objects, u dont really need gson in this scenario.